# JMeter conncurrent threads after seach result

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I have set up a JMeter script:

```
For a number of pages of information
    1) Loads 1 page of information
    2) Parses out a set of elements to be looked up from that page
    3) Queries each of the parsed elements
```

The problem is that (3) above is serial, whereas I need it to be parallel.  Is there a way to do this or better an example?

My test plan outline:

```
Thread group
+ Loop Controller (load more than 1 page of information)
    Counter (Controls the start of my page loading)
  + HTTP Request (Loads the page of information)
      Regular Expression Extractor (To get my elements)
  + ForEach Controller (Varies over my extracted elements)
      HTTP Request (My retrieved elements)
```

The ForEach Controller / and last HTTP Request is what I need to have parallel which is the behaviour in my browser that I'm simulating

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Regular Expression extractor Reference Name is `PARAM` you should be getting something like:

```
PARAM_1=some value
PARAM_2=some other value
PARAM_matchNr=2
```

In order to achieve concurrency you need to **remove** your ForEach Controller and implement plan as follows:

```
Thread group
+ Loop Controller (load more than 1 page of information)
    Counter (Controls the start of my page loading)
  + HTTP Request (Loads the page of information)
      Regular Expression Extractor (To get my elements)
  + HTTP Request (My retrieved elements)
      Synchronizing Timer
```

Associated configuration:

In HTTP Request (My retrieved elements) where you need to refer to `{PARAM_1}` etc. put the following code:

```
${__V(PARAM_${__threadNum})}
```

[__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) -s JMeter Function which returns the number of current thread so dynamic parameter will be ${PARAM_1} for first thread, ${PARAM_2} for second thread, etc.

[Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) pauses threads execution unless specified number of threads will be met. My expectation that you want the number of threads to be equal to Regular Expression match number. To do so place the following into "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" input:

```
${PARAM_matchNr}
```

**Remember that you need to provide enough (equal to match number or more) threads in Thread Group elsewise your test will be hanging infinitely.**

Hope this helps.